# How create Key event and pass it to document?

Tags: javascript, keyevent

I'd like to test key event handler.
I searched and found the result that uses 'createEvent', 'dispatchEvent'.

```
var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
e.keyCode = 83;
e.initEvent(onkeydown, false, true);
document.dispathEvent(e);
```

I did like above but not working.
Could you somebody give me a sample or link?

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.addEventListener('onkeydown', function (e) {
      console.log("onkeydown event raised");
    console.log(e);
 });
 var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
 e.keyCode = 83;
 e.initEvent('onkeydown', true, true);
 document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

You may go through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent)

Answer (score 0):

This is an [obsolete way of handling events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent)

> **Deprecated**
>
> This feature has been removed from the Web standards.
>   Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of
>   being dropped. Avoid using it and update existing code if possible;
>   see the compatibility table at the bottom of this page to guide your
>   decision. Be aware that this feature may cease to work at any time.

If you want to handle keyup events on the entire document, here's the way from the [MDN Documentation of Keyboard events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) :

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  let str = "KeyboardEvent: key='" + event.key + "' | code='" +
            event.code + "'";
  let el = document.createElement("span");
  el.innerHTML = str + "<br/>";
 
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(el);
}, true);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want to achieve I think.

```js
  document.querySelector('.trigger-event').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var e = new Event("keydown");
    e.key="a";    // just enter the char you want to send 
    e.keyCode=e.key.charCodeAt(0);
    e.which=e.keyCode;
    e.altKey=false;
    e.ctrlKey=true;
    e.shiftKey=false;
    e.metaKey=false;
    e.bubbles=true;
    this.dispatchEvent(e);

  }, false);
  document.querySelector('.trigger-event').addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Got keydown ' + e.key);
  },false);

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('keyValue').innerHTML = e.key;
    document.getElementById('charCode').innerHTML = e.keyCode;
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>


  <h3>Demo</h3>
  <p>
    <button class="btn-flat-blue trigger-event">Trigger Keydown event</button>
  </p>




  <h3> Press a key to see the key code</h3>
  <p>
    key <span id="keyValue"></span> = charCode <span id="charCode"></span> 
  </p>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```